# Convert regular class library to ASP.NET 5 (vnext)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a problem referencing libraries in one my existing projects in my new ASP.NET 5 (vnext) project.

I have found no reference on the web about converting existing libraries or changing the compile target.

I've created a new ASP.NET 5 library and it has a different project structure so I'm guessing that's why there doesn't seem to be a way to port them from VS.

Is there any way of doing this other than copying the files? That would create 2 codebases that each need to be maintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's 2 solutions:

**Use Shared code**
You can create an ASP.Net class library and ask it to compile .cs from your other class library. To do that add in your `project.json` add the compile option:

```
{
    ...
    "compile": [ "**\\*.cs", "..\\Shared\\*.cs" ],
    ...
}
```

In this sample the code in `..\Shared` folder will be compiled with the project code.

**Compile your ASP.Net class library for net 4.5**
You can create an ASP.Net class library and ask it to targer the 4.5 framework . To do that add in your `project.json` add the net45 option in frameworks

```
{
    ...
    "frameworks": {
        "net45": { },
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    },
    ...
}
```

in this sample the project target 3 frameworks: 4.5, ASP.Net full and ASP.Net Core

Answer (score 0):

The new project system supports compilation to various build targets including 'classic' .NET project types (class libraries, console etc.). But you do need to use the new project system to use it, which copying files into the new project.

The reason this is might be very useful is that you can maintain a single code base, if you can separate your code by plaform using `#if <framework-target>` blocks to block code from running that is not supported on any of the platforms. `framework-target` in this case is the upper case version of the frameworks entry in project.json (ie NET45,DNX451,DNXCORE50).

To me it looks like the new project system allows to use a single codebase to serve multiple targets. If your code makes that possible then it's a good choice for simultaneously producing multiple outputs from a single project file. This won't work for everything but I think it'll be  good choice for small and very focused modular choices.

If your projects require more project level processing (special ms-build tasks, pre and postprocessing etc.) then the new single project probably won't work so well and you are better off using separte projects for each target. That may change in the future as more options are added to the new project type.